# Can I use psuedo elements as an argument to a scss mixin?

Tags: sass, mixins, scss-mixins

I have a mixin that I'm referencing an "element" as the argument.

```
@mixin themeParent ($child) {
    &--blue #{$child} {
        color: getColour("theme", "bluehighlight");
    }

    &--green #{$child}  {
        color: getColour("theme", "greenhighlight");
    }

    &--purple #{$child}  {
        color: getColour("theme", "purplehighlight");
    }

    &--gossamer #{$child}  {
        color: getColour("theme", "gossamerhighlight");
    }

    &--black #{$child}  {
        color: getColour("theme", "black");
    }
}
```

This works fine if I am referencing an `a` or a `p` for example

HTML

```
<div class="div--blue">
    <a>blue link</a>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
div {
    @include themeParent(a);
}
```

But I want also use the mixin for psuedo elements eg.

```
div {
    @include themeParent(a:hover);
}
```

or

```
 div {
        @include themeParent(>a:hover);
    }


 div {
        @include themeParent(&:first-child);
    }
```

is this possible?
Why is what I'm doing making SCSS not happy :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put your argument in a string.

[DEMO](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/ddd23205c83172f4b92d35e8baef1d4e)

```
@mixin themeParent($child) {
    &--blue #{$child} {
        color: blue;
    }
}

.cool {
  @include themeParent('a:hover');
  @include themeParent('&:first-child');
}
```